# jQuery switch class for menu not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, joomla3.0

I have the following code for menu menu list items to drop down:

```
jQuery(window).ready(function(){

    var timeoutId;
    jQuery('.menuSwitch .menu li').hover(function() {
        if (!timeoutId) {
            timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function() {
                timeoutId = null;
                jQuery(this).children('ul').delay(20).slideDown(200, 'easeInQuad');
           }.bind(this), 200);
        }
    },

    function () {
        if (timeoutId) {
            window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            timeoutId = null;
        }
        else {
           jQuery(this).children('ul').delay(20).slideUp(200);
        }
    });

});
```

Then, I'm switching parent class of the menu Nav, so that this drop-down does not apply on small screens:

```
jQuery(window).resize(function(){   
    if (jQuery(".show-on-small").css("display") == "block" ){
        jQuery('.menuSwitch').switchClass('menuSwitch','menuMobile');
    }
});
```

However, the animation still seems to keep working. Here's brief HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="menuToggler" class="show-on-small">Menu</a><div class="menuSwitch"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="kn_above_header"  style="xhtml" /></div></a></nav></div></div>
```

So, .menuSwitch does get switched to .menuMobile, but the first function still keeps working even though it's only supposed to work for children of .menuSwitch. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It still is happening because you attached the event directly to the element. The event does not magcially get removed when the class is changed.

You can use event delegation to get around it or add a check in the hover code to see what state you are in.

**Event Delgation Solution:**

If you do event delegation, you would have to use `.on("mouseeneter")` and `.on("mouseleave")` since there is no `.on("hover")`.

```
$(document /* or closer parent element */)
    .on("mouseenter", ".menuSwitch .menu li", function() {console.log("mouse enter"}; /*hover enter here */})
    .on("mouseleave", ".menuSwitch .menu li", function() {console.log("mouse leave"}; /*hover leave here */});
```

**Solution to modify your current code**

Or if you want to keep hover, you need to add a check to your current code to see if the class you organically added is there.

```
if (!timeoutId && $(this).closest(".menuSwitch").length) {
```

you might have to change the mouseleave code also.

Comment: Is it either first solution or second, or both? and where exactly would I add a switch? Sorry I'm a total noob.

Comment: You either take your hover code and put it in the one or you put that if statement in your current hover code.